# when i start node.js express application i have strange code instead main page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

when i try start my app.js i have this code in browser instead of my main page:

```
function next(err) {
   if (err && err === 'route') {
     return done();
   }

   var layer = stack[idx++];
   if (!layer) {
     return done(err);
   }

   if (layer.method && layer.method !== method) {
     return next(err);
   }

   if (err) {
     layer.handle_error(err, req, res, next);
   } else {
     layer.handle_request(req, res, next);
   }
 }
```

i use express4.9.8 and node.js v0.10.25
Anybody knows in what could be this problem?

its my first controller who send category list

```
var Category = require('../models/category.js').Category;

// list cateogories
exports.categoryList  = function(req, res, err) {
    if (err) { throw err };
Category.find({}, function(err, cats) {
console.log(cats);
    if(!err) {
        res.render('main.jade', {catList: cats});
    }
})

};
```

and this my my first model code:

```
var mongoose = require('../lib/mongoose.js');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;


var categorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        slug: String,
        order: {
            type: Number,
            default: 99
        }
    },

    error: [{
            type: ObjectId,
            ref: 'Error'
    }]


})



exports.Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

my route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


var categoryController = require('../controllers/categories.js');
router.get('/', categoryController.categoryList);
```

and template:

```
doctype html
html
   head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='style.css')
   title= test
   body
      form(id="search" action="" method="get")
      input(type="text" name="search" class="sfield" value="search and go")
      input(type="submit" value="Search" class="sbutton")
      block content
         ul
            - for (var i in catList)
            li
               a(href='/'+catList[i])= catList[i]
```

Comment: have you tried to log the "cats" object and see what it contains ? It seems that you have a reference to a function, please paste the console.log(cats)

Comment: i add in my categories.js console.log(cats) but i dont see the output(( i edit my question code. you can see where i paste console.log in controller. I try run categories.js or app.js but dont see the output of console.log(cats). what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I find my problem. 
In model code i have reference to not existing model:

```
error: [{
            type: ObjectId,
            ref: 'Error'
    }]
```

Thanks all for your help